# Syntax error unexpected ')' Shopify Dawn 12.0 in a script added by a Speed Optimization Freelancer

Tags: javascript, linux, syntax, shopify

I hired a freelancer to optimize the speed of my site.  She did it pretty quickly and it was scoring in the mid 90s when she was done.  The only thing that seemed off at the time was I was getting a bug in the product page but only on linux desktop.  Windows, android, ios, all loaded the page bug free and fast.  I can comment out this minified line of code which is javascript and everything works as it should.  However, the site speed drops to low 50s and upper 40s.  I also get new errors about monorail failing to load, shopify storefront inbox v2 or something like that and a couple 404 errors concerning something like produce/v2 or something along those lines.  The code is rendered in the theme.liquid file via snippet file meta-tags.  Inside the meta-tags file is your original meta-tags file with the following javascript minified line of code added to the very bottom:

const observer=new MutationObserver(e=>{e.forEach(({addedNodes:e})=>{e.forEach(e=>{1===e.nodeType&&"IFRAME"===e.tagName&&(e.src.includes("youtube.com")||e.src.includes("vimeo.com"))&&(e.setAttribute("loading","lazy"),e.setAttribute("data-src",e.src),e.removeAttribute("src")),1===e.nodeType&&"LINK"===e.tagName&&(e.href.includes("place")||e.href.includes("vimo.com"))&&(e.setAttribute("data-href",e.href),e.removeAttribute("href")),1!==e.nodeType||"IMG"!==e.tagName||e.src.includes("data:image")||e.setAttribute("loading","lazy"),1===e.nodeType&&"SCRIPT"===e.tagName&&("boomerang")==e.className&&(e.type="text/lazyload"),e.innerHTML.includes("asyncLoad")&&(e.innerHTML=e.innerHTML.replace("if(window.attachEvent)","document.addEventListener('asyncLazyLoad',function(event){asyncLoad();});if(window.attachEvent)").replaceAll(", asyncLoad",", function(){}")),(e.innerHTML.includes("PreviewBarInjector")||e.innerHTML.includes("adminBarInjector"))&&(e.innerHTML=e.innerHTML.replace("DOMContentLoaded","asyncLazyLoad")),(e.src.includes("assets/storefront")||e.src.includes("assets/shopify_pay/")||e.src.includes("cdn.judge.me"))&&(e.setAttribute("data-src",e.src),e.removeAttribute("src")),(e.innerText.includes("gtm.start")||e.innerText.includes("webPixelsManager")||e.innerText.includes("cdn.judge.me")||e.innerText.includes("boosterapps"))&&(e.type="text/lazyload"))})})});observer.observe(document.documentElement,{childList:!0,subtree:!0}); (()=>{var e=class extends HTMLElement{constructor(){super();this._shadowRoot=this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}),this._shadowRoot.innerHTML=':host img { pointer-events: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 99vw; height: 99vh; max-width: 99vw; max-height: 99vh;'}connectedCallback(){this._fullImageEl=this._shadowRoot.querySelector("#hell"),this._fullImageEl.src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8000 8000'%3E%3C/svg%3E"}};customElements.define("live-55",e);})();document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ``); {{ 'boldapps.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

I tried removing and adding parenthesis and brackets in the place it was giving the syntax.  I tried to add conditonal statements to make the code more reliable.  I tried having a marketer look over it.  I tried multiple chat events with shopify support.  I tried to paste the code in v.s. code editor and debug it there.  I was expecting that a ')'  could simply be removed to fix the error.  I actually spent hours trying differnt tools to help debug the code.

Comment: Please put your code in a ```code block```. We cannot unminify this because it has a syntax error, which means we are unable to help.
Actually, why did you minify your code anyway? It's a non-reversible process and you're looking for help.

Comment: I did not minify the code.  It was done by a speed a freelancer named speedy from Fiverr.  She minified the code.  And the reason it was minified was to improved load time.

Comment: michael-odell do you have the unminified code? without the original source code, we can't really do much to help, despite what Onkar is trying

Comment: No.  I don't even know where the code came from.  It's not in that location in the stock theme.

Answer (score 1):

Use this un-minified version of the code in place of the above code.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver((e) => {
  e.forEach(({ addedNodes: e }) => {
    e.forEach((e) => {
      1 === e.nodeType &&
        "IFRAME" === e.tagName &&
        (e.src.includes("youtube.com") || e.src.includes("vimeo.com")) &&
        (e.setAttribute("loading", "lazy"),
        e.setAttribute("data-src", e.src),
        e.removeAttribute("src")),
        1 === e.nodeType &&
          "LINK" === e.tagName &&
          (e.href.includes("place") || e.href.includes("vimo.com")) &&
          (e.setAttribute("data-href", e.href), e.removeAttribute("href")),
        1 !== e.nodeType ||
          "IMG" !== e.tagName ||
          e.src.includes("data:image") ||
          e.setAttribute("loading", "lazy"),
        1 === e.nodeType &&
          "SCRIPT" === e.tagName &&
          "boomerang" == e.className &&
          (e.type = "text/lazyload"),
        e.innerHTML.includes("asyncLoad") &&
          (e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML
            .replace(
              "if(window.attachEvent)",
              "document.addEventListener('asyncLazyLoad',function(event){asyncLoad();});if(window.attachEvent)"
            )
            .replaceAll(", asyncLoad", ", function(){}")),
        (e.innerHTML.includes("PreviewBarInjector") ||
          e.innerHTML.includes("adminBarInjector")) &&
          (e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(
            "DOMContentLoaded",
            "asyncLazyLoad"
          )),
        (e.src.includes("assets/storefront") ||
          e.src.includes("assets/shopify_pay/") ||
          e.src.includes("cdn.judge.me")) &&
          (e.setAttribute("data-src", e.src), e.removeAttribute("src")),
        (e.innerText.includes("gtm.start") ||
          e.innerText.includes("webPixelsManager") ||
          e.innerText.includes("cdn.judge.me") ||
          e.innerText.includes("boosterapps")) &&
          (e.type = "text/lazyload");
    });
  });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: !0, subtree: !0 });
(() => {
  var e = class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      (this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })),
        (this._shadowRoot.innerHTML =
          ":host img { pointer-events: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 99vw; height: 99vh; max-width: 99vw; max-height: 99vh;");
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      (this._fullImageEl = this._shadowRoot.querySelector("#hell")),
        (this._fullImageEl.src =
          "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8000 8000'%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }
  };
  customElements.define("live-55", e);
})();
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", ``);
{{ 'boldapps.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Comment: Than didn't work.  It caused more errors to occur.  Now have a syntax for < and several monorail failures and a couple other new errors.  There's a typo in the code somewhere or something not right.

Comment: You need to share the URL of the website, so anyone check the console and able to configure what is actual cause

Comment: Okay.  Here's the link: https://odellcreations.com.  thanks for helping me on this.

Comment: any Shopify preview URL on which the un-minify code was added, so test the same also?